# Is it possible to solve a linear polynomial in a finite field

Tags: multivariate-cryptography

Say that in $\mathbb{F}_{999,999,000,001}$ I have an equation $0 = ax - b$ where $a$ and $b$ are random values from the field.

Is it possible to solve this equation for $x$ using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm without a brute force search?

If instead I was in a finite field with order as a 254 bit prime, would this problem be intractable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not intractable. Moreover a solution always exists provided $a\neq 0$ (if $a$ is zero the solution is $x=0$).

For any $p$ prime, any $a\neq 0,$ in the field $\gcd(a,p)=1,$ and thus $a^{-1}$ can be efficiently computed via the extended Euclidean algorithm. Thus $x=a^{-1}b$ is efficiently computable.

Both the gcd, and the multiplication have relatively low complexity (see comment by @fgrieu) essentially no worse than
$O((\log p)^3).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I had a multivariate linear polynomial like $0=ax + by - c$ would finding the root for $x$ and $y$ be similar or would it be much more complex?

Comment: The complexity of the multiplication is larger than $\mathcal O(\log p)$; at least $\mathcal O(\log p\log(\log p))$ in theory ([Harvey and van der Hoeven's result](https://doi.org/10.4007%2Fannals.2021.193.2.4)), up to $\mathcal O((\log p)^2)$ by elementary algorithms. The complexity of GCD is larger, I think $\mathcal O((\log p)^2\log(\log p))$ to $\mathcal O((\log p)^3)$.

Comment: Thanks, I was being a bit sloppy.

Comment: For 2 variables, fix $y=y_0$ and apply given idea to find $x.$ The complexity for each fixed $y$ is as before.

Answer (score -1):

denote your field by $K$ and let $p= 999 999 000 001$.
what do you think about $ x= b  a^{-1} $ when this quantity is well defined?
clearly this requires that $a$ to be invertible mod $p$
this means that this linear equation to have a unique solution $x =ba^{-1} \mod p$  if and only if $gcd(a,p) = 1$

since this is efficiently computable then this problem is not intractable.
when $gcd(a,p) \not= 0$ this means that $gcd(a,p) = p$ because $p$ is prime and so $ax-b = pkx - b  = -b$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,
and hence the equation becomes $0 = -b$ this is only true when $b=0$,
if $b$ is not a zero then this linear equation has no solutions in $K$.

Comment: in $−$ what is the $k$ variable?

Comment: $k$ is some constant from $\mathbb{Z}$